# Get Bone to track another armature

Tags: armature, bones, tracking

I have 2 armatures, the first has a static root bone that does not move, the others can only rotate on the Z axis, I am trying to get the last child bone to track the second armature, the second armature only moves up and down.

I want the last bone in the link to track the second armature and to cause all the parent bones connected to it, apart from the root bone rotate to keep all the bones connected.

This is for a "Digger" like object where the Root would be the base of the vehicle that does not move, and by graving and moving the bucket the rest compensates appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I Managed to accomplish this through trial and error. First going from the second bone (first child after Node) I added two Constraint's.

First add a "Damped track" and target the same armature as the bone, and target the next bone in the armature, Bone_2 targets Bone_3, 2->3, 3->4.

Second add a "Limit rotation" constraint keep everything default and Limit X, Y, and Z.

On the last, Tail Node add only 1 Constraint: A "Inverse Kinimatics" Target is Armature 2, Bone x.

After all this the first armature will fallow the second one, keeping its constraints.

EDIT: I made a small mistake the last Bone (Tail) constraint is not a Spline IK, but an Inverse Kinimatics constraint.